# assigning dynamic href of a link to another link with PHP

Tags: php

I have this problem. On my website I want to show the content of a folder with links. And if I click this link i want it to assign the source of the file to another link/button. So if I click the download button it downloads the file I clicked on.

this is what i got to show the files as links:

### PHP

```
<?php
$path = "./files";

$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
  if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" )
  continue;
    echo "<a href=\"".$path."/".$file."\">$file</a><br />";
}

closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

so this makes a link of every file in the folder but I cant figure out how to assign the source of the file I click on to a download button/link. Atleast I don't know a way that doesn't make a download link for every file.

Comment: Your code looks valid. Please elaborate what you are trying to do. That is not clear yet.

Comment: He listed the files in his directory. Now he wants a way to download it.

Comment: The usualy way to do something like this is to use javascript. But in pure PHP, you could have each file link link back to the page but with a query string parameter like "?file=$filename" at the end. Then in the download button you put $filename in the source. This is an old fashioned way of doing this though.

Comment: That way would be clicking the link. There would be nothing more to do.

Comment: Keith I understand what you mean but wouldn't that just grab the last file that gives it href to the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and note that this may not work depending on server and php settings. I am assuming you are using properly configured Apache (or Apache-comparable) server:

```
<?php

// Get the document root the server or virtual host is pointing to
$docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$docrootLen = strlen($docroot);

// realpath to get the full/expanded path to the files directly
$path = realpath('./files');

$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" )
        continue;

    // Create fileUrl by removing $docroot from the beginning of $path
    $fileUrl = substr($path, strpos($path, $docroot) + $docrootLen) . '/' . $file;

    echo '<a href="' . $fileUrl . '">', $file, '</a><br />';
}

?><a id="download-button"></a><?php

closedir($dir_handle);
```

For the "another link" part, notice I added an extra anchor tag above with the ID "download-button". This will be the download button. At the end of your HTML (before the closing body tag), you can add this script inside a `<script>` tag:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), linkIdx;
for( linkIdx in links ) {
    if( links[linkIdx].getAttribute("id") == "download-button" ) {
        // These are not the anchor tags you are looking for...
        continue;
    }
    links[linkIdx].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        // When the user clicks the link, don't allow the browser go to the link:
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("download-button").setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("href"));
        document.getElementById("download-button").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    });
}
```

Comment: This works thanks. but i also want to assign the href of the file to a download button/link after i clicked on it. I tried to just put in $fileUrl but then it just grabs the last file like i expected

Comment: @jeroenmager - What you are asking sounds more like you need JavaScript to change the href of another element in the browser when you click on a file link. If you have some code that is giving an error with that you can post it and I will take a look. Technically that is out-of-scope of your question. You may considering altering your question or asking a separate question for that.

Comment: I see now, you only asked in the title of the question. I will update my answer with a simple solution.

Comment: i don't mind using javascript in the code as long as it works. and i'm sorry for not being really clear about it i'm kind of new in stack overflow and the programming world in general. But i tried with javascript and got it working until the point he placed the href of the file but only the first one. i will post that code soon if i can retrieve it

Comment: @jeroenmager - Ok, I have updated the code with a script that should do what you are asking.

Comment: It does not work it says a is not defined at line:
    a.addEventListener("click", function(e){

Comment: Oops, I was thinking about anchor tags and typed "a" instead of the link variable. I updated the answer.

Comment: this works just like i wanted thank you so much i have been stuck on this problem for a long time